# Gaming Mouse Detected as a Keyboard

Tags: udev, mouse, xinput

I was given a gaming mouse from a company I had never heard of before as a gift. Naturally, it doesn't work. When I first plugged it in, the LEDs lit up, and that was that. No movement, no buttons -- nothing works. From the following snippets, it seems it is detected as a keyboard. How can I fix this?

cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[358259.417] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SINOWEALTH Game Mouse (/dev/input/event10)
[358259.417] (**) SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[358259.417] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SINOWEALTH Game Mouse'
[358259.417] (**) SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: always reports core events
[358259.417] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[358259.417] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[358259.417] (II) event10 - SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[358259.417] (II) event10 - SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: device is a keyboard
[358259.417] (II) event10 - SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: device removed
[358259.433] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1/0003:258A:1007.0006/input/input18/event10"
[358259.433] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SINOWEALTH Game Mouse" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[358259.433] (II) event10 - SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[358259.433] (II) event10 - SINOWEALTH Game Mouse: device is a keyboard
```

lsusb -v -d 258A:1007

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 258a:1007  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x258a 
  idProduct          0x1007 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 SINOWEALTH
  iProduct                2 Game Mouse
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     213
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a device like a rubber-ducky disguised as a mouse?

Comment: I can't be positive, but the site seems too sophisticated to be just a scam. The site given for drivers is [here](www.etpc.cn). I received a moderately detailed instruction booklet too.

Comment: If you move the mose/click any of the buttons with xev open in terminal, does anything show up?

Comment: Nothing seems to correlate with the mouse. The light on the bottom of the mouse does get brighter when moved, so I wouldn't think it's a dud.

Comment: most wireless mice are composite keyboard/mouse devices even if the receiver is only paired with a mouse. That's usually not a problem. Please also add the output of `lsusb -v -d 258A:1007` to your question.

Comment: @mosvy Updated.

Comment: my Roccat is identified as keyboard too but it works fine, thus I don't think this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely won't work for everyone, but I solved it by simply restarting my computer. Probably should have done it first, but it's been a while since I needed to restart it to fix something.